# Extract photos from a photo album using Python

Tags: python, opencv, contour, canny-operator

I have a physical photo album, for which each page might contain one or more photos glued on it.

I took a picture of each individual page, containing multiple photos.
Now, I placed all the pictures that I took into a single folder, and I would like to iterate over it with Python to extract all photos that were glued on that page.

I have the following Python script, but the downside of this script is that it finds way too many contours (on the pictures itself as well).

What is a good (alternative) method for getting the contrasts right when the page's background is white?

```
# Read the image
img = cv2.imread("images/" + image)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Show gray image
cv2.imshow('Gray Image', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)



# Apply edge detection using the Canny edge detector
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

min_area = 50000
filtered_contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if min_area < cv2.contourArea(cnt)]

extracted_photos = []
for i, contour in enumerate(filtered_contours):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    extracted_photos.append(img[y:y+h, x:x+w])
    # Uncomment the following line to save individual photos
    # cv2.imwrite(f'photo_{i}.jpg', image[y:y+h, x:x+w])

# Show the extracted photos
cv2.imshow('Original Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

for i, photo in enumerate(extracted_photos):
    cv2.imshow(f'Photo {i}', photo)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Original photo

[image: Original]

## Grayscale photo

[image: Grayscale]

## Contours

[image: Contours]

Comment: Could you show an example page and the results?

Comment: Added a nice example (removed recognizable parts after exporting the python imshow)

Comment: Right, this is made much more complicated by the fact that the rectangles (photos) are _overlapping_.

Comment: making it easy wouldn't be fun :)

Comment: Are there two photos for every page ? To overcome the overlappings you should now hom many photos (or overlappings same thing) are there.

Comment: @BarışAktaş first sentence of my question: "each page might contain one or more photos glued on it." so, no not two by definition. One or more can be any number

Comment: Okay then, seems like the best approach is filter > find lines > intersect lines > get rectangles. Can you share an example with 3 image in one page.